# Expression of $\kappa_S$ in photon gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I'm calculating some properties of the photon gas. That gas is defined by 
$$U=aVT^4$$
$$P=\dfrac{1}{3}aT^4$$

I calculated photon gas entropy:

$$S = \dfrac{4}{3}aT^3V $$

I could calculate $c_V$. Also, I know that $c_P$ and $\kappa_T$ are not defined because it's impossible to change temperature at a constant pressure. Now I'm trying to calculate $\kappa_S$, defined as

$$\kappa_S = -\dfrac{1}{V}\left(\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_S $$

This parameter looks defined, because, in principle, I can variate $P$ at constant $S$, that will have effect on $V$. It's difficult to write $V=V(P,S)$ so I'm trying to calculate it using:

$$\kappa_S = -\dfrac{1}{V}\left(\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_S =
-\dfrac{1}{V}\left(\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_S \left(\dfrac{\partial T} {\partial P}\right)_S = -\dfrac{1}{V}\left(\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_S \left(\dfrac{\partial P} {\partial T}\right)_S ^{-1}
$$

That gives me a value of 
$$\kappa_S = \dfrac{27}{16} \dfrac{S}{Va^2T^7}$$

which looks really strange. I think I'm not calculating it correctly, and my reasoning in partial derivatives is not correct.
 My question is, is $\kappa_S$ really defined in the photon gas and which is its expression? What am I doing bad?

Comment: Try substituting in the final result the expression for $S$. You get a much simpler form, which can also be derived directly from the $V=V(p,S)$ (not that difficult, really; try it out!)

Comment: I've tried with lot of combinations, but I always obtain $V=V(P,S,T)$ and in that case, I can't derive because $T=T(P)$, and if I substitute $T$ I come back to the original expression. How can eliminate $T$ from my expression?

Comment: Well, you know $p(T)$, so just invert it. It is even easier to determine the adiabatic index $\gamma$, such that $pV^{\gamma} = Cst$ for constant $S$, because you can obtain $\kappa _S$ without writing down the constants explicitly.

Comment: Oh, that's true. I've calculated that equation before, $\gamma=4/3$. I can simply use that formula. Thank you! :D